# Redis HMSET with multiple fields or multiple HMSET for lookups

Tags: .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am new to Redis. I have a scenario where I need to put millions of items in Redis cache for later lookups. Each entry also need to be expired, if it is not used for a period of time.

One way to do is, a HMSET with fields and values, and another HMSET to track the expiry time (lots of book keeping)

Second option is to have HMSET for every entry with expiry time set to them. (Easy way, I guess).

My question, whether Redis is desiged to have millions of HMSET lying around ? Will it degrade the performance of Redis as more and more HMSET is introduced for every entry to the cache ? 
A follow up question. Is the same applies, if I were to use string data types ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to retrieve them. If you use HGET for a single field, that's O(1), but HMGET is O(N) . Likewise GET for a single string item is O(1) but MGET is O(N): the basic rule is the more data you want to get back, the longer it will take. It seems the easiest approach here is to set the TTL when you insert the items so that they automatically expire at some point, and reset the TTL when you a GET so that they stay alive.

Comment: @howcheng I think you misunderstood the *HMGET* It is clearly written in the documentation that O(n) is for *n* number of fields requested, so accessing one field is O(1). The same applies for MGET. My question was to clarify whether I need to keep every entry as a standalone (sort of scattered around) or in one place with book keeping. It will take just too much to read up all the documentation to understand the inner workings of Redis. It was easy to ask others who already done something with it or had the opportunity to understand it.

Comment: Yes, HMGET with one field is the same as HGET. I didn't misunderstand; I just assumed that if you were using HMGET/SET then you were intending to multiple fields at the same time (because that's the purpose of those commands),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using hash is more memory efficient: https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization
- memory saving is varied based on settings of `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and `hash-max-zipmap-value`
- using hash won't allow you to expire individual field of a key and like you set, you need another hash for book keeping. you can write Lua script for inserting data and book keeping ttl data; saving some roundtrip time.
- it's fine to have millions of hash
- if you feel the hash is too big, you can always chunk it. eg taking `id` modulus with `1000` for example so id < 1000, will go to hash `0`, etc.... this way you will end up with less hash

Comment: **it's fine to have millions of hash** Can you please give me a reference to the source where read about it. I am asking it because I am writing a service and I don't want it to go into production and the technical decision I make become a bottleneck.

Comment: From redis faq itself https://redis.io/topics/faq . personally, i've deployed many small services with redis holding over 1M+ keys already and it never was an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I appreciate your time. It did answer my question.